# mysql - #1064 syntax error when creating a procedure using case for rand()

Tags: mysql, database, if-statement, case

I am getting #1064 error. I want to use rand() together case or if else statement. I tried every solution but I achieved no result. This is my sql query:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `pgetVideos`(pName varchar(100), positionID int)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
            ID,
            userID,
            createddate_,
            duedate_,
            title,
            description,
            videourl,
            categoryID,
            positionID, 
            imagePath
    FROM 
        videos
    WHERE 
        videos.isDeleted<>1 AND 
        (positionID=0 OR videos.positionID = positionID) 
    ORDER BY 
        CASE pName
            WHEN 'video1' THEN RAND() LIMIT 10
            WHEN 'video2' THEN RAND() LIMIT 4
            WHEN 'video3' THEN RAND() LIMIT 6
            WHEN 'video4' THEN RAND()       
        END CASE;

END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Also I tried this code:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `pgetVideos`(pName varchar(100), positionID int)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
            ID,
            userID,
            createddate_,
            duedate_,
            title,
            description,
            videourl,
            categoryID,
            positionID,
            imagePath
    FROM 
        videos
    WHERE 
        videos.isDeleted<>1 AND 
        (positionID=0 OR videos.positionID = positionID) 
    ORDER BY 
        IF pName = "video1" THEN
           RAND() LIMIT 10
        ELSE IF pName = "video2" THEN
           RAND() LIMIT 4
        ELSE IF pName = "video3" THEN
           RAND() LIMIT 6
        ELSE IF pName = "video4" THEN
           RAND()
        END IF;

END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: You can't put `LIMIT` after `RAND()`.

Comment: The syntax is `ORDER BY <expression> LIMIT <limit>`. The expression is the whole `CASE ... END` expression.

Comment: @Barmar How can I run `LIMIT` case by case;? I want to assign different values to it in different cases.

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` expression just returns a value, and `LIMIT` is not part of a value. You're not substituting into the text of the query, you're returning a value that should be used when ordering the results.

It's not possible to use a computed expression in the `LIMIT` clause. But since you're doing this in a stored procedure, you can generate dynamic SQL using `PREPARE`.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `pgetVideos`(pName varchar(100), positionID int)
BEGIN
    SET @limit = CASE pname
        WHEN 'video1' THEN 'LIMIT 10'
        WHEN 'video2' THEN 'LIMIT 4'
        WHEN 'video3' THEN 'LIMIT 6'
        WHEN 'video4' THEN ''
    END;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('
        SELECT 
            ID,
            userID,
            createddate_,
            duedate_,
            title,
            description,
            videourl,
            categoryID,
            positionID, 
            imagePath
        FROM 
            videos
        WHERE 
            videos.isDeleted<>1 AND 
            (positionID=0 OR videos.positionID = positionID) 
        ORDER BY RAND() ', @LIMIT);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I have a error in this line when executing on query: `$result = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql) or die ("Query error: ".$sql." ".mysqli_errno().":".mysqli_error());`